# Can not access OTG USB Key after just after Granting ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, usb-drive

My phone is a Samsung A32 5G ( SM-A326B/DS).
Android 12, native ROM, SDK 31.

I need to read files from OTG USB dongle from 2 apps :

- My app which is an installer. It install some APK and restore some data external SD card or OTG USB Device.
- Termux app, dowloaded from github and modified to request the right.

The manifest includes :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

To request in java code I tried 2 methods :

First method :

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
          if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
CTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                String name = getPackageName();
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", name, null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

Second method :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 501);
    }
}
```

In two apps, the problem is that it the authorization does not take effect inside the Activity which asked the authorization.
Even if I end my Activity with finish() and start again my App, I have not the access.
But if I kill my app with task manager and start the app, the I get the right.
But when I kill my app with the task manage and start it again, then I access the USB dongle.

In both app, to access the ISB Key I use linux commands.

- With `mount` command I check that the USB Dongle is seen by Android.
- With `USBPATH=$(grep -E "^[^ ]+ /mnt/media_rw/[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4} " /proc/mounts | cut -d' ' -f2)` I get the path of the dongle
- With `ls $USBPATH` I see that I have not the right, even after MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has been granted, because ls returns "permission denied".

Comment: Please show the code you use to access the usb otg drive.

Comment: `My problem is that it seems that the authorization does not take effect inside the Activity which asked the authorization.` HArd to believe. Please show the code which leads you to that conculsion.

Comment: For the rest i wonder what the Android version of used device would be as for modern Android versions you will not get a path to the dive anymore. No path then manage external storage does nothing. We have to use SAF to access a usb drive. Please tell what kind of device you have.

Comment: `I need to kill my app with the task manage and start it again.` Pretty bad and not needed as using a finish() at back key at activity end will do.

Comment: `My problem is that it seems that the authorization does not take effect inside the Activity which asked the authorization. ` Then put that as subject of your post. All has nothing to do with usb otg drives. Know your problem! Dont confuse us.

Comment: One advice. Use startActivityForResult() instead. You will see that Environment.isExternalStorageManager() gives the right value in onActivityResult.

Comment: And i wonder which Android 12 device you use that you can do without SAF for an USB drive,

Comment: @blackapps, thanks for helping me. I modify my post to add the information you required. About Android release, I have no additional information than 12. Tell me which getprop result I could give you.

Comment: It seems that the permission is granted to the package, not to the running Activity. Thats why I need to relaunch my app to get the access right to USB Dongle.
It seems that if my Activity call finish(), the context is not clean, that why if I launch again I have not the right. Is there a way to call finish() and clean every data of the activity ?

Comment: `seems that the permission is granted to the package, not to the running Activity.` You said that before and we asked to tell how you came to that conclusion. Further that is not true as everything in the whole app has all files access then.

Comment: Further you keep talking about usb otg which has nothing to do with your problem. Please rewrite your post to concentrate on the problem that your activity would not directly have all files access. Wel it has and you can see that if you use startActivityForResult. Well i said that before... You are not even reacting..

Comment: `I get the path of the dongle` You did not tell us which path exactly.

Comment: My problem is exactly the object of the post : "Can not access OTG USB Key after just after Granting ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"
My problem is accessing  the OTG USB fongle. Perhaps that when I'll have the solution I'll find a better description of my problem, but for the moment I can tell more than "I cannot access my USB dongle"
The path is /mnt/media_rw/ (return by my shell command).

Comment: My java code for executing shell command works, it is not the problem. This code works for all linux command : df, mount, cp, grep, sed, and  bash of 20  lines.
 When I execute "ls -l /mnt/media_rw/ " from my code, mi code returns "permission denied"
If I kill and launch again my app, "ls -l /mnt/media_rw/ " from my code returns the list of files and directory of my USB Key.

Answer (score 0):

You have no read access to /mnt/media_rw.

All files access has no effect on it.

Comment: I have not access to /mnt/media_rw
But I have access to /mnt/media_rw/XXX-XXX  (this path is returned by mount | grep ..)
But I only access it if I kill and start again my app after the user have grant MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE when the setup menu is open by my app (this menu can also be open manualy  by Prameters / Applications /  Special access / Access all files).

Comment: I guess the permission is grant to the package and not the running Activity, because it is not asked by the Activity, the activity only open the setting menu. The activity pass the package name as parameter, but it is not to grant the permission to itself, it is only to position the setting menu a the place of the application. I think it is not possible to change that.

Comment: So a solution for me could be to erase all data of my activity after finish(). After a finish(), the next Activity launched when I start the app as also not the permission. To get the permission I must manually kill the Activity, then start again the app, and then it works.
So a sub-question is : is there a way more strong that finish() to terminate an activity. Something like finish()+destroy every data related to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It is probably a dirty solution, but it works.
The problem was to terminate my Activity just after the user manually grant the right MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, knowing that :

- even after the user grant the permission, my Activity did not have the right (1)
- more over, if I end my Activity by finish() and start the app again, the new activity have not the right. I do not find explanation for that , It look like the new activity keep some context of the previous one.

My solution is to kill my pid. I had implemented in my app the ability to launch bash commands. So I kill the pid of my Activity after launching new activity:

```
static String HaraKiri = "sleep 2;PID=$(ps -ef | grep     'eu.eduphone.install' | grep -v  'grep' | grep  -v 'eu.eduphone.install.' |awk '{ print $2 }');echo \"PID=$PID\";kill -15 \"$PID\"";
    ...
private void Restart() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String name=getActivity().getPackageName();
    Log.d("Thierry", "Restartn Name = "+name);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(name, name+".MainActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
    ShellExec(HaraKiri);
}
```

That works, the new activity can read the USB Dongle.

**(1) About the reason what we must restart Activity to get the right after the user grant it :**

In another discussion, https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/71#issuecomment-1869222653 , https://github.com/agnostic-apollo says that :

- Unreliable/Removable volumes like USB OTG devices that are only
  available on the /mnt/media_rw paths with their own filesystem
  (vfat/exfat) are assigned the root (0) owner and external_storage
  (1077) group.
- If an app has been granted the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE    permission,
  then the external_storage (1077) group is added to list    of groups
  that are assigned to the app process when its forked from    zygote,
  allowing it to access unreliable/removable volumes with the
  external_storage (1077) group.

My running activity is not in the group 1077 because it has been forked before this group was assigned to the app.

Comment: I have the impression my approach is a tad more elegant and it works at least with microSD. If any group is being assigned, it is being assigned to the user running the app, possibly with the scope of the app ...therefore I think this reasoning doesn't make sense (I even know it, because it just works).

Answer (score 0):

It's not required to kill the app, when waiting until the user pressed the back button.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
public void gotoExternalStorageSettings() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", requireContext().getPackageName(), null));
    this.startActivityAndWait.launch(intent);
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityAndWait = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), (ActivityResult result) -> {
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                // permission was granted
                // continue in here ...
            }
        });
```

The culprit otherwise is indeed, that the app does not know when.
There isn't any result returned, but one does not need any result ...